# Adding scss file type to new context menu of PyCharm

Tags: python, sass, pycharm, jetbrains-ide

The JetBrains IDE PyCharm supports scss files, but I can't figure out how to add it to the "New" context menu that pops up when right-clicking the directory where I want to add the file.

I see a lot of other file types, and looking at registering a new file type, I see scss is already there. But I can't figure out how to add it to the "New" context menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

New SCSS files can be created via `File/New/Stylesheeet`. But you can create your own SCSS file template in `Preferences | Editor | File and code templates` (see https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/creating-and-editing-file-templates.html) - new templates will appear in `File/New` menu.